# PHP retry value to string

Tags: php

I have this problem:

One string like:

```
$stringa = "array('name' => 'John')"
```

I want obtain : `array('name' => 'John')` for use in my code like array

Any helps? Thanks

Comment: You can serialize your array and read by unserializing.

Comment: How do you end up with that string in the first place?!

Answer (score 3):

Caution using [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)...

> Caution The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it
>   allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged.
>   If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to
>   use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user
>   provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

```
<?php
$stringa = "array('name' => 'John')";
$code = "\$a = " . $stringa . ";";
eval($code);
print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Gouda Elalfy was on the right idea, but his solution simply made the whole string a single array value.

First, we need to remove the excess datatype information:

```
$slimString = substr($stringa,6);
$slimString = rtrim($slimString,")");
```

This now gives us a string of:

> ```
> 'name' => 'John'
> ```

So then the `Keys` and the `values` in the string need to be split up,
so break at `=>` as so:

*For multiple values in the string:*
This method also includes the single quotes to limit catching punctuation commas (please note this method was screwed up by `trim` not being as effective as I'd have liked and requiring str_replace quotes instead).

```
$slimString = str_replace("', '","=>", $slimString);
```

Then

```
$slimStringParts = explode("=>", $slimString);
```

This will split on `=>` (*or `,`*) so that multiple values of array contents can be generated.

Then cycle through each of the array pieces, on the basis that the *EVEN* numbers (and zero) are the `Keys` and the *ODD* numbers are the `values`, also removing the quotes as well for each one,

I was originally using `trim` but for some reason trim was not working as fully as I expected. so instead reverted to `st_replace`

```
foreach($slimStringParts as $key => $part){
    if(($key%2) == 0){
    $part = str_replace("'","",$part);
    $arrayOutput[$part] = str_replace("'","",$slimStringParts[$key+1]);
    }
} 
unset($key, $part);
```

The foreach only acts upon the even and zero values as referenced above, and they take the original key value + 1 as their contents.
The `trim`/`str_replace` removes the single quotes and looks untidy but this works for a string of *one or more* array values

And finally the Output:

```
 print_r($arrayOutput);
```

Test with the original:

> input :  "array('name' => 'John')"
>
> Output : Array ( [name ] => John )

Tested with a multivalue array string:

> input : "array('name' => 'John', 'surname' => 'James', 'Ride' => 'horse')"
>
> Output : Array ( [name ] => John [surname ] => James [Ride ] => horse )

Full code:

```
$stringa = "array('name' => 'John')";
$stringb = "array('name' => 'John', 'surname' => 'James', 'Ride' => 'horse')";
$slimString = substr($stringb,6);
$slimString = rtrim($slimString,")");

$slimString = str_replace("', '","=>", $slimString);
$slimStringParts = explode("=>", $slimString);

foreach($slimStringParts as $key => $part){
    if(($key%2) == 0){
        $part = str_replace("'","",$part);
        $arrayOutput[$part] = str_replace("'","",$slimStringParts[$key+1]);
    }
}
unset($key,$part);

print_r($arrayOutput);
exit;
```

Please note my `trim()` idea was what I wanted but that seems to be influenced by my page character encoding :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval()` function.

But it's **not recommanded**.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

**Eval is unsafe**, try to use it as temporary method and find a better solution.

Example :

```
$stringa="array('name' => 'John');";
$array = eval($stringa);
```

Comment: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in ... : eval()'d code on line 1**

Comment: If it is not recommended then really why post it? `Eval` in this situation is somewhat like trying to kill a hamster with a hand-grenade. And the risk are significant, even more so if the string is from an input, which it almost certainly is otherwise this OP situation can be more easily solved.

Comment: Because this method exists and that it answers the question. But i agree with you

Comment: whit eval work!! but i add ; at the end. Why is not recommanded?

Comment: Since the you edited to add `;`, `var_dump($array);` is giving me `NULL` now... (_PHP Version 7.0.2-2_)

Comment: I've edit and add the ';' at the end 3 min ago. Try to use it as a temporary method

Comment: $stringa = "array('name' => 'John');";
$whereClause = eval($stringa); this code work